# GetSet in C# not being parsed

Tags: c#, .net, console, getter-setter

Relatively minor question about something I am missing here,

I am attempting to do a simple GetSet in `C#` to get the hang of the syntax but appear to have missed something as all that is printed is `GetSet.Role` and not the actual attributes being assigned.

Have I just worded something wrong? Apologies for the minor question but any help is appreciated.

```
namespace GetSet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Role Mage = new Role("Staff", "Robes", "Magic affinity");
            Role Warrior = new Role("Sword", "Platebody", "Strength");
            Role Rogue = new Role("Needle", "Leather", "Cunning");

            Console.WriteLine(Mage);
            Console.WriteLine(Warrior);
            Console.WriteLine(Rogue);
            //stop the program from closing
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and the following is my class:

```
namespace GetSet
{
    class Role
    {
        //private variables
        private string weapon;
        private string armour;
        private string passive;

        //public structs
        public Role(string aWeapon, string aArmour, string aPassive)
        {
            weapon = aWeapon;
            armour = aArmour;
            passive = aPassive;
        }

        //Getters and Setters for above private variables
        public string Weapon
        {
            get { return weapon; }
            set { weapon = value;}
        }
        public string Armour
        {
            get { return armour; }
            set { armour = value;}
        }
        public string Passive
        {
            get { return passive; }
            set { passive = value;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code itself in the question, instead of images.

Comment: ahh ok, I will edit it in then, apologies

Comment: also, there is some comments that are wrong worded. What you are calling `private variables` is actually `private fields`, and if they used as a value store of a property (like in your code) we calling them `backing fields`. What you are calling `public structs` is a `public constructor`, `struct`s are complitly different things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `ToString` method on the GetSet class.

Something like:

```
public override string ToString() 
{
     return $"{weapon}/{armour}/{passive}";
}
```

---

## Update

You can simplyfy your `Role` class.

```
internal class Role
{
    public Role(string weapon, string armour, string passive)
    {
        Weapon = weapon;
        Armour = armour;
        Passive = passive;
    }

    public string Weapon { get; }

    public string Armour { get; }

    public string Passive { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Weapon}/{Armour}/{Passive}";
    }
}
```

---

Re: vasily.sib's comment.

If you need to change the properties after object creation then simply change

```
public string Passive { get; }
```

to

```
public string Passive { get; set; }
```

Comment: I doubt about simplification, as from code in question there are public setters, so I think that readonly properties is not an option here:\

Comment: @vasily.sib The posted code does not use setters. (BTW. That's why the **original** example code worked - the setters had a bug in it.)

Comment: Not sure what bug are you talking about, but as Ben is trying to learn something about getters and setters, I'm pretty sure he need some setters

Comment: @vasily.sib The original code was 'set { Passive = value;}' (note the capital 'P').  

When you're saying 'pretty sure', what are you basing it on?

Comment: I'm basing on a logic, that I can't learn something about setters with a code without setters

Comment: You can learn that setters are not needed. Immutable classes have significant benefits. The class Ben is creating sounds like a class for a game. Games are often multi-threaded. Immutable classes are great in multi-threaded apps.

Comment: Well, I think it is not for us to decide if _"setters are not needed"_. Also, immutable classes have one significant disatvantage - they are immutable. For example, immutable mages can't change their weapons or armor - isn't this game will be boring?

Answer (score 1):

Add a  `ToString()` to your Role class and set it return whatever you want:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Weapon: {weapon}, Armor: {armor}, Passive: {passive}";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers lacks of getters/setters syntax examples, I will post my.

```
namespace GetSet
{
    public class Role
    {
        // private backing field
        private string _weapon;

        // properties can have getters and setters, that contains some logic
        public string Weapon
        {
            get { return _weapon; }
            set { if (_weapon != vale) _weapon = value; }
        }

        // there is an auto-getters/setters
        // in this case, backing field is handled by .Net CLR
        public string Armour { get; set; }

        // getters and setters may have different access level
        // also, note property initializer '= "John";' - this will set property value
        // to "John" right before constructor invocation
        public string Name { get; private set; } = "John";

        // properties also can be readonly, so they can be setted only in constructors
        public string Passive { get; }

        // public constructor
        public Role(string passive)
        {
            Passive = passive;
        }

        public void ChangeName(string newName)
        {
            Name = newName; // setting property through private setter
        }

        // I believe, that this method shouldn't be used to represent object as string
        // At least, I think, you should never relay on it's return value, BUT it ups to you
        public overide string ToString() => Name;
    }
}
```

Also, as you can see, I'm not setting publicly available properties (properties with public setters, `Weapon` and `Armour`) in consturctors, because I can initialize them along with constructing `Role` object, like this:

```
var mage = new Role("Magic affinity") { Weapon = "Staff", Armor = "Robes" };
mage.ChangeName("John, Doe");
```

As said before, I beleive that it is not relay on object itself, how it will look in string. I thinking so, because if you for some reasons need to represent same object as different strings in different places of your code - this will cause troubles. So instead of this:

```
// this will call .ToString() method
Console.WriteLine(mage);
// output: John, Doe
```

I suggest this:

```
// represent object as you need
Console.WriteLine($"{mage.Name} - walks in {mage.Armour}, beats with {mage.Weapon}");
// output: John, Doe - walks in Robes, beats with Staff
```